# Oracle data decryption in SQL Server 2012 using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, encryption, ssis

The scenario is

The data should be stored in oracle in encrypted format. It needs to be retrieved from oracle and then again stored in sql server in encrypted format. I am using SQL Server 2012 and SSIS.

Please suggest

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve and what exactly does "encrypted format" mean?  Both Oracle and SQL Server (depending on version, edition, and licensed options) support transparent data encryption (TDE) in which case the data is encrypted at rest and then transparently decrypted by the database for any user that is authorized to view the data.  You would never see encrypted data though.  That may or may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi

The requirement is to secure data at rest so nobody is able to read it including DBAs. The challenge is, when data is encrypted in oracle it is very difficult to dycrypt same in SQL server

Comment: If you are encrypting the data to prevent DBA's from reading it in Oracle, you must either be using Data Vault or implementing encryption in the application with a key that is not available to the DBA.  If the application is implementing encryption, the encrypted data should be stored as `RAW` or `BLOB` data in the Oracle database.  You could then move that binary data to SQL Server into a `VARBINARY` column and the application should be able to decrypt it..